# Apple MacBook Air mid-2012

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, disk-utility, kernel-panic

A few days ago, I got my Macbook Air battery changed at an Apple store. Since then, about once a day, I've had a "kernel panic" crash, which seems to happen randomly while I'm working. (I've never seen this before.)

I did an extended memory test, which showed no problems, but a disk test on the built in 128 Gb SSD showed these errors:

Checking catalog file.(It should be 67667 instead of 67668)
Invalid directory item count(It should be 38 instead of 37)
Invalid volume free block countFile system check exit code is 8.

The popup advised repairing the disk using the Recovery HD (Command R on startup). I've done this, but, from the recovery screen, the disk shows no errors, and Verify says the disk is fine. When I rerun the disk check inside OSX, the same messages pop up.

Any idea what's going on here? Is it possible that the hard drive was damaged during the battery install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some "corruption" on some of your files.  Since you already ran the Disk Utility and it came back clean it is telling you that there are no physical errors with your drive.  That's the good part.

You have a couple of options:

- Run fsck
- Do a clean install

**Running fsck.**  You will need to do so in single user mode (hold down Command-S during boot)

You will know that this worked because you will see a black background with a ton of white text scroll down your screen.

When you are done booting, you will see a command line prompt.  Enter the following command:

```
#fsck -fy
```

(Don't enter the hash tag)

It will complete and tell you that the file system was modified.  Keep running the above command until it tells you that the volume is "Ok."

When you are done reboot the computer by issuing the command

```
#reboot
```

Your MBP Air will reboot normally the error should go away.

If it dosen't it is time to do a fresh clean install.

There are third party utilities that "may" work here, but I have found they cause more problems than they are worth.

Oh...most important part:

**Make sure you have a backup of all your data!!!!**